# Is there a complete physical archive of Weekly Shounen Jump (or Shounen Sunday or Shounen Magazine)?

Tags: manga-history

Considering that *Weekly Shounen Jump* (or *Sunday* or *Magazine*) have given rise to many franchises of great cultural significance, **is there a library, museum, or some place that has a complete physical archive of these periodicals**, in Japan or anywhere else? If there is any such archive, I would think that'd be an interesting place to visit.

Comment: Tangentially related - anime studios have been known to lose the original cels for anime that were produced back in the pre-digital days, thus preventing the release of remastered high-res digital versions based on the original cels. Similarly, I suspect that there is _not_ a complete archive of the original "masters" (not sure what the word is) for _Shounen Jump_ or any other sufficiently-long-running serialized magazine. But as for whether there is an archive of the magazines themselves - now that's an interesting question!

Comment: @senshin I didn't think any animation company, Japanese or otherwise, treated their cels as anything other than disposable after production finished. (At least until they started to become collectible enough to be worth selling off, but in Japan that happened almost as soon as things went digital) There was never any possibility of any anime being remastered from the original cels. http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/answerman/2015-12-07/.96188

Answer (score 3):

At least, It should be in [National Diet Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Diet_Library).

Under Japan's law, all publishers need to submit 1 copy of all of their books and magazines to that library.

Some people [succeed to read Jump in there](http://halciondays.sakura.ne.jp/gallery.n/library.html), but it's not a normal library. You may need pre-reservation and require security to enter, but you can search their item from [their official website](http://www.ndl.go.jp/).